# Not able to push into array from subroutine in perl

Tags: arrays, multithreading, perl

I am using multithread and want to push local time of each thread into array.
I can print to localtime from thread successfully, but it wont push time into array. Printing array is not giving blank.

Please check.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/Perl
use threads;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my @arr=();
my $num_of_threads = 2;
my @threads = initThreads();

foreach(@threads){
         $_ = threads->create(\&doOperation);
         }

foreach(@threads){
         $_->join();
         }

foreach(@arr){
         print "$_\n";
         }

sub initThreads{
            my @initThreads;
            for(my $i = 1;$i<=$num_of_threads;$i++){
                push(@initThreads,$i);
             }
            return @initThreads;
        }

sub doOperation{
        ##doing my main operation here
        my $a=localtime();
        print "$a\n";
        push(@arr,$a);
        }
```

Comment: Side note, `my @threads = map { threads->create(\&doOperation) } 1 .. $num_of_threads;`

Comment: You probably want a Thread::Queue rather than an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads don't share variables. See [threads::shared](http://p3rl.org/threads::shared).

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
my @arr :shared;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`threads::shared`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html) which enables you to share variables among threads,

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my @arr :shared;
# ...

sub doOperation {

    my $a = localtime();
    print "$a\n";
    {
      lock(@arr);    # advisory exclusive lock for variable
      push(@arr,$a);
    }                # lock get released when going out of scope
}
```